# C++ How do I pass a system serial number into a variable?

Tags: windows, variables, serial-number, wmic

I've been able to retrieve my system serial number, but how do I pass the serial number itself into a variable?

```
    int main()
    {
        char newSerial;
        int (*ptr) (const char[]);

        ptr = system;

        ptr("wmic bios get serialnumber");      
    }
```

After running my code, the screen displays:

```
    SerialNumber
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

exactly like this. But what I want is to pass just the "x's" into a char variable since it has a dash in it. Where exactly is the program calling the serial number from? Any suggestions? (Windows 7 x64)

Comment: maybe you want to use the `popen` function.

Comment: This code can't be responsible for formatting  the result shown - there's no print statement.    You dont have direct access to the results of a system call

Comment: @AShelly 1. Run it yourself. 2. Then go to your DOS prompt and type the sentence that's passed into my ptr. 3. You can also add this line: system("wmic bios get serialnumber"); You will see your system serial number all 3 ways. Dont forget to add stdlib to your list of 'includes.

Comment: Right, but in all those cases it is a different program then yours which is printing the result.   You do not have direct access to the serial number string from your program.    You could construct the system call to redirect the result into a text file which your program could the read, I guess.

Comment: @AShelly I already knew I don't have direct access to where the computer stores the serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The officially sanctioned way to get programatic access to WMI through C++ is the [COM API for WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).   See specifically the examples under  [WMI C++ Application Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If on the other hand, you want quick access to the serial number, add something along these lines to your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*...*/

system("wmic bios get serialnumber > sn.txt");
wchar_t sn[16];

FILE* fp = fopen("sn.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-8");
fgetws(sn, 16, fp); //dummy read of first line
fgetws(sn, 16, fp); //`sn` now contains 2nd line

fclose(fp);          //cleanup temp file
remove("sn.txt");

printf("The serial Number is: %ws\n", sn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better approach without using text file

```
QProcess proc;
//proc.start("cscript " + path, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
proc.start("wmic bios get serialnumber",QIODevice::ReadWrite);
//qDebug() << path;
proc.waitForFinished();
QString uID = proc.readAll();
qDebug()<<uID; // serial number of the laptop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/c wmic bios get serialnumber > sn.txt", NULL, SW_HIDE);

wchar_t sn[16];
FILE* fp = fopen("sn.txt","r, ccs=UTF-8");
fgetws(sn,16,fp); //dummy read of first line
fgetws(sn,16,fp); //now sn contains 2nd line

fclose(fp);          //cleanup temp file
remove("sn.txt");  

printf("The serial Number is: %ws\n",sn);
```