# How to get system serial number?

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi

from c # I got the system serial number with the help of this code (not me)

```
public static string getSystemSerialNumber()
{
    string mbInfo = string.Empty;
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();
    ManagementObject wmiClass = new ManagementObject(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_BaseBoard.Tag=\"Base Board\""), new ObjectGetOptions());
    foreach (PropertyData propData in wmiClass.Properties)
    {
        if (propData.Name == "SerialNumber")
        {
            mbInfo = Convert.ToString(propData.Value);
            break;
        }
    }
    return mbInfo;
}
```

it returns the following string: /8ZBPX**/CN12966791****/
, I want to get exactly string above but using c++ (windows10). i found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139312/c-how-do-i-pass-a-system-serial-number-into-a-variable/9168306#9168306):

```
system("wmic bios get serialnumber > sn.txt");
    wchar_t sn[16];

    FILE* fp = fopen("sn.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-8");
    fgetws(sn, 16, fp); //dummy read of first line
    fgetws(sn, 16, fp); //now sn contains 2nd line

    fclose(fp);          //cleanup temp file
    remove("sn.txt");

    printf("The serial Number is: %ws\n", sn);
```

and it returns the following string: 8ZBPX**, I didn't know how to find the information chain behind.

How can i get full system serial number in c++?
Many thanks!

Comment: Is the content of 'sn.txt' correct?

Comment: Hi @Dominique, Sorry but I don't even know how to find this file!.

Comment: Your piece of code creates the file and removes it. I'm proposing you to alter your piece of code, remove the line which removes the file, test and check the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SO answer you referenced: [C++ How do I pass a system serial number into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168306/6610379)

references some MSDN links, one of which directs you to [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer).

This article is a good starting point for creating your conversion of the '`getSystemSerialNumber`()' function from your question.

Taking the code from that article verbatim, you can change just a couple of lines to convert it to query for serial number (a few other comment lines and output lines should be changed as well for clarity/correctness).

You can then further modify the '`main`()' function to return the value to mimic your C# function.

Here's the modified version:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // Query the system board
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Baseboard WHERE Tag = \"Base Board\""),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for system board serial number failed."
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Serial Number property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " Serial Number : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```

The effective lines that were changed are as follows:

1. You'll see that the `SELECT` statement looks similar to your C# `ManagementPath` constructor call:

   ```
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Baseboard WHERE Tag = \"Base Board\""),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
   ```
2. Query for the correct property:

   ```
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
   ```

I didn't tidy this up intentionally (there are so many opportunities, e.g., `using namespace std;` needs to go, smart pointers should be used throughout, etc.), but left it intact so that you can compare to the original MSDN code.